# How many symmetries can a countable set $\mathfrak X\subset\Bbb R^d$ have?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, symmetry, discrete-geometry, automorphism-group

Let $\mathfrak X\subset\Bbb R^d$ be a *full-dimensional* and *countable* subset. Full-dimensional means that $\mathrm{span}(\mathfrak X)=\Bbb R^d$.
How large can its symmetry group

$$\mathrm{Aut}(X):=\{T\in\mathrm O(\Bbb R^d)\mid T\mathfrak X=\mathfrak X\text{ set-wise}\}.$$

be? I suspect it can be at most countable, but I have no argument for that.

Comment: What do you mean by full dimension? In any case, a symmetry as you describe it can be thought of as a homomorphism $O(\mathbb{R}^d) \to Perm(X)$, where the latter group is the group of permutations of $X$. This might help

Comment: @leibnewtz I can't see how. If $\mathfrak X$ is infinite, then $\mathrm{Perm}(\mathfrak X)$ is certainly uncountable, but this says nothing about $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak X)$, or does it?

Comment: Maybe it doesn’t. But just a thought: it seems like there could be very few rotations fixing a discrete set $X$. If you have a set of $n$ points, then my guess is that there are at most $2n$ rotations fixing this set, with $2n$ being achieved only if all points lie on the same sphere of some fixed radius

Comment: Ah wait, that should only work in two dimensions. But nevertheless, a rotation fixing $X$ is a rotation fixing the subset of points lying on a given sphere. I think you should be able to show there are only countably many of these

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed at most countable. By the full-dimensionality assumption $\mathfrak X$ contains a basis $e_1,\dots, e_d$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$. You may then define the map
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\Phi & : & \textrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{X}) & \to & \mathfrak{X}^d \\
   &   & T & \mapsto & (T e_1,\dots, Te_d).
\end{array}
$$
Since the elements of $\textrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{X})$ are by assumption linear, $\Phi$ is injective. However, since $\mathfrak{X}$ is countable, so is $\mathfrak{X}^d$ and the result follows.

Comment: +1 What a very beautiful argument!

Comment: In addition it works with the whole group of linear automorphism (or even affine automorphisms, assuming in addition that $G$ affinely generates the space).